# Android Studio how to show full error message

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio only shows part of the error message. And when I mouse over the error in Build window, the message is too long and goes off screen. How can I see the whole thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out I have to click on the tiny toggle button (-/ab) on the left to show full message

[image]